# UIDocumentInteractionController - Change background Color and prevent status bar popup

Tags: ios, colors, uikit, statusbar

When I use the **UIDocumentInteractionController** it's background color is always white in the beginning and when I tap it, it gets black (and back when tapped again).

Can I somehow invert this or even set a custom background color for both modes?

Another interesting bug is that once I touch the screen the status bar (which I have disabled) pops back up. So white screen with document --> tap screen --> black background with status bar --> tap white screen withs status bar.

Once I dismiss that UIDocumentInteractionController, I disable the status bar again but it looks really ugly.

I've got the info.plist set up correctly with UIViewController-wise decided status bar appearence set to NO.