# iOS: How to change UIDocumentInteractionController's background color when tapped

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

As I searched on Google, this question has been asked by several users before, but no one answered, for example:

[UIDocumentInteractionController - Change background Color and prevent status bar popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705492/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-change-background-color-and-prevent-status-bar)

It seems some people like me really hope to know what we can do to change the documentController's background color when it enters full screen. Now, the default is black. The thing is, UIDocumentInteractionController is not a subclass of UIViewController, but a subclass of NSObject instead, which makes it impossible to access its "view" property directly.

So I hope to know what might be done to change its background color?

Comment: I am also interested in this